# Attempting to step through columns in a search

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I am attempting to create a module in Excel 2016 that will scan through a sheet and auto size any comments found.  My current code requires me to adjust the Column Letter each time I run it.  I am looking for a method to step through the columns in my loop. My current code is listed below and I am thanking anyone ahead of time for any assistance I can get.  My current sheet only uses columns A through P.

```
Sub cmtsize()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect pswd

    Range("a7:I7").Select
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For xrow = 7 To lrow
        xcell = "c" & lrow
        Range(xcell).Select
        If ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
            GoTo nxt
        Else
            With Range(xcell).Comment.Shape
                .TextFrame.AutoSize = True
            End With
nxt:
        End If
    Next xrow

    ActiveSheet.Protect pswd
    Range("A6").Select
    MsgBox "Finished!"
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the cells in column **C**.  What columns do you want to loop over??

Comment: look at using `OFFSET` so another loop say xcol and then `Range(xcell).offset(0,xcol)` where xcol will be like 1=A,2=B,3=C and so on.

Comment: Just a note, but I recommend to read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). Also avoid `GoTo`, instead negate your `If` statement with `Not` like `If Not ActiveCell.Comment Is Nothing Then {do autosize} End If`

Answer (score 3):

This will resize all comments on the specified worksheet.  [Update] included option for password protected sheets.  As well as the Finished Msgbox.

```
Sub test()
    Call ResizeComments(Sheet1)
    MsgBox ("Finished!")
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeComments(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal Pass As String = "")
    If Pass <> "" Then ws.Unprotect Pass

    Dim oComment As Comment
    For Each oComment In ws.Comments
        oComment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    Next

    If Pass <> "" Then ws.Protect Pass
End Sub
```